# What is the name of the book depicting the story of a boy who finds a settlement of various creatures on a tree?

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember reading a story of a boy finding a settlement of various creatures on a tree. Some points which may help in figuring out the book are as follows.:

- The book was in English.
- The title may contain "tree" or "willow".
- The story was at least 300 pages long and was directed for a young audience but was also a perfect adult read.
- I read it about ten years ago.
- I suppose that the settlement always experienced night.
- I think the settlement was lighted with lanterns.
- As the boy climbed the tree, he made new friends and finally reached the clouds.

I can be a little off in the details but would be grateful if someone could provide the nearest match to this story. One may clear any further doubts in the comments.

Comment: It helps work out which book you are looking for by narrowing the number of options. There are other things that could help. It is worth reading [This page](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) to see if it jobs any memories.

Comment: @Jontia is it okay now?

Comment: This is definitely an improvement. :) So, was the tree really big initially? Did it grow while being climbed? Did the boy shrink to scale? Was the boy part of the tree from the beginning? Was the boy's nationality equivalent to one of ours on Earth?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots thank you for your reply. I have found about the book. Still, thanks to you all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The book is "**[The Enchanted Wood](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Enchanted_Wood_(novel))**", a children's novel, and is the first book in "[The Faraway Tree](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Faraway_Tree)" series written by [Enid Blyton](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enid_Blyton).

In the novel Jo, Fanny, and Bessie discover an enormous tree, the Faraway Tree, whose branches seem to reach into the clouds.

> When the children climb the Faraway Tree they discover it is a very strange tree, such as one which grows apples and pears, nuts, acorns and oak leaves and all sorts! Different magical creatures live there. They become friends with these people.